# What does m(i) represent in the following program? c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn some OOP and I have a problem understanding the following program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A(int i) : m(i){}

    friend class B;

    friend void g_afiseaza_m();
private:
    int m;
};

class B
{
public:
    void afiseaza_m()
    {
        A a(250);
        cout<<"clasa B este prietena cu clasa A"<<endl<<" poate accesa membrul privat A::m"<<endl<<a.m<<endl;
    }
};

void g_afiseaza_m()
{
    A a(300);
    cout<<"functia g_afiseaza_m nu este un membru al clasei A dar este prieten"<<endl<<"poate accesa membrul privat A::m"<<endl<<a.m<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.afiseaza_m();
    g_afiseaza_m();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Can you please tell me what does this line do: public:A(int i) :m(i){} private: int m?
I undestand that A is a constructor with the int parameter i, and that m is a private member of class A but I can't understand what is m(i) ? Is this a matter of syntax ?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `m(i)` in your constructor initializes the `m` member with value `i`.

Your example has the same outcome (and not behaviour) as

```
A(int i) {
    m = i;
}
```

Initializing members using initializer lists as in your example is more efficient because the member's constructor is called directly with parameter `i` whereas in the example above, the empty constructor of `m` is called and *then* `m` is assigned value `i`.

Comment: In the example above, they're exactly the same. It's non-POD types that make a difference in performance.

Answer (score 5):

That's a constructor initializer list, it initializes the member `m` of the class with the specified value.

It's there to prevent initialization followed by immediate assignment in some cases (not here).

Some members can only be initilized in the initializer list - `const` members, reference members, types that aren't default-constructable.

Answer (score 5):

```
A(int i) : m(i) {}
         ^^^^^^ this is called member-initialization list.
```

Here `m(i)` means `m` is being initialized with `i`.

If you have more members, say, `x`, `y` in your class, then you can write this:

```
A(int i) : m(i), x(i*10), y(i*i) {}
```

So all the 3 members are initialized *before* entering into the constructor body.

See these topics for more detailed answers:

- [Why should I prefer to use member initialization list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list)
- [Prefer member initialization list to assignment](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/init-lists.html)